# Issues running 'Deploy TestAgent' step for selenium tests in TFS2017

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm attempting to use the 'Deploy TestAgent' step as part of my build so I can run Selenium tests. Unfortunately I keep running into the following error...

```
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' for machine DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985's Error : System.Exception: Unable to find TestAgent installation path
```

The full log file is as follows...

```
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy TestAgent on DESKTOP-K88UM6R
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z ==============================================================================
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z Task         : Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z Description  : Deploy and configure Test Agent to run tests on a set of machines
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z Version      : 1.0.42
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=625976)
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3449184Z ==============================================================================
2017-05-05T16:30:46.3605675Z Preparing task execution handler.
2017-05-05T16:30:46.8620069Z Executing the powershell script: C:\Build Agent\TFS\Builds\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\DeployTestAgent.ps1
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0116105Z DistributedTests: Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0297456Z DistributedTests: Inputs provided are:
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0297456Z DistributedTests: Username: DESKTOP-K88UM6R\matty
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0302506Z DistributedTests: Use HTTP Port: True
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0302506Z DistributedTests: Run as process: True
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0307486Z DistributedTests: Login Automatically: True
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0307486Z DistributedTests: Disable Screen saver: True
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0312658Z DistributedTests: Agent would be downloaded from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0312658Z DistributedTests: Update test agent: True
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0312658Z DistributedTests: Run test agent as DataCollection only : False
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0317489Z DistributedTests: Path to script that installs test agent on remote machine: C:\Build Agent\TFS\Builds\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\TestAgentInstall.ps1
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0317489Z DistributedTests: Path to script that configures test agent on remote machine: C:\Build Agent\TFS\Builds\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\TestAgentConfiguration.ps1
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0317489Z DistributedTests: Path to script that downloads test agent on Azure remote machines : C:\Build Agent\TFS\Builds\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\DownloadTestAgent.ps1
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0322465Z DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is installed on remote machine: C:\Build Agent\TFS\Builds\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\CheckTestAgentInstallation.ps1
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0322465Z DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is already running on remote machine: C:\Build Agent\TFS\Builds\_tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent_52a38a6a-1517-41d7-96cc-73ee0c60d2b6\1.0.42\VerifyTestMachinesAreInUse.ps1
2017-05-05T16:30:48.0322465Z DistributedTests: Path to script that helps to download and configure test agent : 
2017-05-05T16:30:48.1305296Z DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' is being run
2017-05-05T16:30:52.1708691Z DistributedTests: Task 'PopulatingMachinesPresentState' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' completed.
2017-05-05T16:30:52.1865084Z DistributedTests: Starting to download testagent
2017-05-05T16:31:04.3843950Z DistributedTests: testagent is downloaded at: C:\Users\matty\AppData\Local\Temp\7ff37613-bc34-4f69-afb1-7128d841678f
2017-05-05T16:31:04.7161264Z DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' is being run
2017-05-05T16:31:06.1901171Z DistributedTests: Task 'CopyFilesToTestAgent' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' completed.
2017-05-05T16:31:06.1901171Z DistributedTests: Task 'DeployTestAgent' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' is being run
2017-05-05T16:31:09.9855530Z DistributedTests: Task 'DeployTestAgent' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' completed.
2017-05-05T16:31:10.0011806Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' is being run
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985' completed.
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' for machine DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985's Error : System.Exception: Unable to find TestAgent installation path
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' for machine DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985's Log : 
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z     Deployment started on target machine...
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z 
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z System.AggregateException: Failed to execute the powershell script. Consult the logs below for details of the error.
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z Unable to find TestAgent installation path ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find TestAgent installation path ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find TestAgent installation path
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<Invoke>b__0()
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9263760Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute[T](Func`1 action)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.ScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(IPowerShell powerShell, String script, String arguments, Boolean isScriptDotSourced, Boolean useHttp)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.DeploymentService.RunPowerShellScripts(DeploymentMachineSpecification deploymentMachine, ScriptSpecification scriptSpecification, ScriptSpecification initializationScriptSpecification, String applicationPath, IPowerShell powerShellSession)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find TestAgent installation path ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Unable to find TestAgent installation path
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<Invoke>b__0()
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute[T](Func`1 action)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)<---
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z Finding whether TestAgent configuration is required
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z 
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z Getting existing configuration
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z 
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z 
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z ##[error]Error occured on 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985'. Details : 'Unable to find TestAgent installation path'. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9419999Z ##[error]System.Exception: Error occured on 'DESKTOP-K88UM6R:5985'. Details : 'Unable to find TestAgent installation path'. For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9732454Z ##[warning]For troubleshooting, refer https://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9732454Z ##[error]System.InvalidOperationException: Deploy Test Agent task has failed on all machines. Check the logs for more details.
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9732454Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.DeployTestAgent.Run()
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9732454Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.TaskRunner.Run(Dictionary`2 arguments, VssConnection connection, TaskType taskType)
2017-05-05T16:31:13.9732454Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.InvokeDeployTestAgentCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-05-05T16:31:14.0266415Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 2 errors.
2017-05-05T16:31:14.0266415Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy TestAgent on DESKTOP-K88UM6R
```

I can see the vstf_testagent file appear in my Temp folder during a build but am confused as to why it's then complaining about the installation path.

Here is some more info

- I'm on windows 10
- The solution I'm building contains selenium tests only.
- I'm attempting to build and deploy the test agent on the same machine which is my own machine.
- I have run the PSRemoting powershell script (Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force)

many thanks

Comment: Which test agent are you using agent 2015 or agent 2017？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test agent location** in Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task:

> Optional. The path to the test agent (vstf_testagent.exe) if different from the
>   default path.
>
> - If you use a copy of the test agent located on your local computer or    network, specify the path to that instance.
> - **The location must be accessible by either the build agent (using the    identity it is running under) or the test agent (using the
>     identity    configured above).**

According to `Unable to find TestAgent installation path` error. Instead of downloading the agent from internet, you could manually download the agent first.  Then put the VS 201x Test Agent on a **share** folder and have the VS Test Agent Deployment task deploy it. (Do not install the agent locally)

Besides if you are using test agent 2017. You need fist update TFS2017 to TFS2017 update1. There is a "**Version**" drop-down at the top right hand corner of each Task that . You need to use "Version 2" of the VS Test Agent Deployment task so that you could properly configure it to deploy the VS 2017 Test Agent.

Comment: Hi Patrick. Manually downloading the test agent did seem to work thanks. I am using TFS2017 update 1 and had the deployment task set to version 2.